# Android ImageView shows as the correct size for an image, but doesn't display the image

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog, imageview

I have a TextView with ImageSpans set up, allowing it to display images.
The images fill the width of the TextView and show correctly, however this can still be too small if an image has lots of detail such as text.

I want to show the image in a dialog when the Image is clicked.

First I added onClick listeners to the Images as follows

```
private void enableImageClicks(final Spannable s) {
    for(final ImageSpan span : s.getSpans(0, s.length(), ImageSpan.class)) {
        s.setSpan(new URLSpan(span.getSource()) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                if(mImageClickHandler == null) {
                    super.onClick(widget); //Opens image link
                } else {
                    mImageClickHandler.imageClicked(span.getDrawable());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        }, s.getSpanStart(span), s.getSpanEnd(span), s.getSpanFlags(span));
    }
    setText(s);
}
```

I have tried two methods to display the image.

The first being a dialog with a transparent background and the drawable in an ImageView as follows

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

final ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);
iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);

dialog.addContentView(iv, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//Log.i(TAG, "imageClicked: Drawable " + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + ", " + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

dialog.show();
```

The dialog shows with the transparent overlay, but the image doesn't show.
I can see that the drawable has width and height, and the LayoutInspector shows that the ImageView has the correct dimensions.

Secondly, I tried defining a layout in XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

and

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, null);

builder.setView(view);

 ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview)).setImageDrawable(drawable);
builder.create().show();
```

however this has exactly the same problem as before. The dialog shows and the ImageView has the correct dimensions but no image is shown.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the drawable loaded your image?

Comment: Yes, it shows in the TextView.